# Chinese indexes doesn't enumerate according to phonetic ordering

Tags: indexing, phonetic

A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{ctex}
%%%index setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
m
\index{康托}
\index{完全性}


\cleardoublepage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I compile it by `XeLatex` and get the following PDF:

[image]

I found the indexes doesn't enumerate according to Chinese phonetic ordering, otherwise `康托` should be before `完全性`.

**Question:** ***Who can help me to make the indexes enumerate according to Chinese phonetic ordering?*** By the way, I use MacTex.

Comment: I don't think that even Xindy knows how to sort Chinese, let alone MakeIndex that just knows about the Latin alphabet without diacritics.

Comment: @egreg I use `imakeidx` to produce three kinds of index enumerations. I don't know whether there are other ways which can split indexes into three kinds and also enumerate them according to phonetic ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As egreg mentioned in the comments, neither Makeindex nor Xindy support Chinese, but here's a different approach.

I don't have `ctex` installed, so I've switched to XeLaTeX with `fontspec`. If you want to use PDFLaTeX then it's slightly more complicated.

This method uses [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). Instead of using `\index`, the terms are first defined in one or more `.bib` files. For example, `entries-zh.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{康托}

@index{完全性}
```

With PDFLaTeX, you need ASCII labels, for example:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{label1, name={康托}}

@index{label2, name={完全性}}
```

(Choose more appropriate labels. I don't know any Chinese.)

The document:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceHanSansCN-Regular}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
  nostyles,% don't load the default styles
  stylemods=bookindex,% load glossary-bookindex.sty
  style=bookindex % set the default style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries-zh},% data in entries-zh.bib
  sort={zh}% sort by this language (zh = Chinese)
]

\begin{document}
m 
\glsadd{康托}\glsadd{完全性}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

This is the closest equivalent to your MWE where `\glsadd` behaves like `\index` in that it indexes but doesn't display any text. The argument of `\glsadd` is the *label*, so if you are using the above ASCII labels:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceHanSansCN-Regular}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
  nostyles,% don't load the default styles
  stylemods=bookindex,% load glossary-bookindex.sty
  style=bookindex % set the default style
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries-zh},% data in entries-zh.bib
  sort={zh}% sort by this language (zh = Chinese)
]

\begin{document}
m 
\glsadd{label1}\glsadd{label2}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Index}]
\end{document}
```

If the document is called `test.tex` then the document build is:

```
xelatex test
bib2gls test
xelatex test
```

This produces:

[image: Index 康托, 1 完全性,1]

If you want letter groups, you need to use the `--group` (or `-g`) switch:

```
xelatex test
bib2gls -g test
xelatex test
```

This now produces:

[image: Index 康 康托, 1 完 完全性,1]

Instead of `\glsadd` you can use `\gls` to additionally display the associated text in the document.

You can have multiple indexes. For example, suppose `entries-en.bib` contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{cat}
@index{dog}
```

Then:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceHanSansCN-Regular}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
  nostyles,% don't load the default styles
  stylemods=bookindex,% load glossary-bookindex.sty
  style=bookindex, % set the default style
  nomain % don't create default 'main' glossary
]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{index-zh}{Index (Chinese)}
\newglossary*{index-en}{Index (English)}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
   src={entries-zh},% data in 'entries-zh.bib'
   sort={zh},% sort by this language (zh = Chinese)
   type={index-zh}% put these entries into the 'index-zh' glossary
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
   src={entries-en},% data in 'entries-en.bib'
   sort={en},% sort by this language (en = English)
   type={index-en}% put these entries into the 'index-en' glossary
]

\begin{document}
Chinese: \gls{康托} \gls{完全性}.

English: \gls{cat} \gls{dog}.

\printunsrtglossary[type={index-zh}]
\printunsrtglossary[type={index-en}]
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: Chinese: 康托 完全性. English: cat dog.]

Page 3:

[image: Image of Chinese index]

Page 5:

[image: Image of English index]

For hierarchical entries, you need to use the `parent` field. (The value is the *label* of the parent entry.) Example:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{康托}

@index{完全性}

@index{的妻子,
  parent={康托}
}

@index{的弟弟,
  parent={康托}
}
```

The document can be edited to include these new terms:

```
Top-level terms: \gls{康托} and \gls{完全性}. 
Sub-entries: \gls{的妻子} and \gls{的弟弟}.
```

Page 1 now has the text:

[image: Top-level terms: 康托 and 完全性. Sub-entries: 的妻子 and 的弟弟.]

and the index on page 3:

[image: image of index with sub-entries listed under their parent entry]

The `bookindex` style uses `\glsxtrbookindexprelocation` for the separator between the term and the location (page number). This is defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\glsxtrbookindexprelocation}[1]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield{location}{#1}%
  {,\glsxtrprelocation}%
  {\glsxtrprelocation}%
}
```

(where `\glsxtrprelocation` is just a normal space). This checks if the `location` field is set. It won't be if the parent entry isn't indexed. (If the `location` field isn't set then a space is used to allow the style to have some limited functionality with the standard makeindex/xindy options that don't set that field.) So to use a dotted leader as the separator:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrbookindexprelocation}[1]{%
  \glsxtrifhasfield{location}{#1}%
  {\dotfill}% location provided
  {}% location field not set
}
```

When you invoke `bib2gls` with the `--group` (or `-g`) switch, it creates a `group` field for each entry. The value of this field is a *label* which will typically be an alphanumeric identifier. An associated title corresponding to that label is set with `\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{`*label*`}{`*title*`}`. This is performed in the `.glstex` through helper commands provided at the start of the file.

In the above example, the relevant lines in the `.glstex` file are:

```
\bibglssetlettergrouptitle{{康}{康}{142540800}{index-zh}}
\bibglssetlettergrouptitle{{完}{完}{232259584}{index-zh}}
```

The default behaviour is to create the group label by concatenating the glossary type (`index-zh`) with the numeric value obtained by the comparator used by the sorting method. The corresponding title is set to the associated letter (which may be more than one character).

So in this example, the first group label is `index-zh142540800` with the corresponding title 康 and the second group label is `index-zh232259584` with the corresponding title 完.

You can change the titles after `\GlsXtrLoadResources` using these group labels. For example:

```
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{index-zh142540800}{X}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{index-zh232259584}{Y}
```

The internal mechanism used by `\printunsrtglossary` inserts a new group header every time the group label changes. So two labels with the same title would still be treated as two different letter groups. You can change the way the grouping is formed by creating your own custom sort rule (but that's more complicated).

Comment: Too complicated, but maybe a possible way!

Comment: But how to produce the second level glossary, for example, if we want to add `wife` under `康托`?

Comment: @Kuttens Do you mean you want hierarchical entries or do you want to mix English and Chinese in the same glossary at the same hierarchical level?

Comment: @Talbot, I mean how to produce `的妻子` under `康托` and `的弟弟 ` under `康托`.

Comment: @Kuttens I've added a hierarchical example. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Talbot, Yes! Also I want the Chinese group labels are English letters not Chinese Characters, and further 康托 and the page number is filled with dots.

Answer (score 1):

Try `zhmakeindex`.

```
pdftex mylatexfile
zhmakeindex -s zh.ist mylatexfile
pdftex mylatexfile
```

In the above, `zh.ist` is the index style file used in `zhmakeindex` documentation.